# sqlsoup Insert Ignore

Tags: python, sqlsoup

I'm using sqlsoup to handle a MySQL database, and I'd like to run the following SQL:

```
INSERT IGNORE mytable SET col1=value1 col2=value2 vol3=value3
```

Is there a way to do this using sqlsoup? I seem to have a hard time finding information on anything more complicated than the standard queries for sqlsoup in general. Is there a resource I'm not finding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read sqlsoup tutorial first. There is db.yourtable.insert  method to do the work.
https://sqlsoup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html